# take x items from list where each one has a unique value for a certain property

Tags: c#, list, linq, .net-core

If I have an array of objects like so:

```
public class Expert
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Availability { get; set; }
}
```

where rating can be any one of the following: [1,2,3,4,5]

I want to retrieve 5 items from the list where each item has a different rating.

So I want to end up with a list of 5 items where 1 has a rating of 1, another has a rating of 2 and so on up to 5.

Comment: You are aware that in theory you have no guarantee that the set of items have at least one item for each rank.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I have updated to show the full class outline. 
and Tarik yes I am aware, it can return less than 5 if certain ratings do not exist

Comment: @DanielBrown - Please respond to one person per comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `GroupBy` then project the `First` result with `Select`

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Rating)
                 .Select(x => x.First());
```

or as mentioned by @Enigmativity in the comments, it gives a certain degree of flexibility

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Rating)
                 .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1));
```

**Further reading**

[Enumerable.GroupBy Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1)

> Groups the elements of a sequence.

[Enumerable.Select Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Enumerable.First Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netcore-3.1)

> Returns the first element of a sequence.

Comment: While the `.Select(x => x.First())` pattern works immediately after a `GroupBy`, I'd suggest using `.SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))` instead as it is more robust to a `Where` being inserted after the `GroupBy` and it is more flexible in allowing `Take(n)` if needed. In other words, it's more robust when refactoring.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be to group by rank then to select the first element of each group. Trivially feasible in line.

Comment: I value the time I spend policing. It's my contribution to the community. Your answer is, in my opinion, only half an answer. If someone doesn't know how to group and select the first element of each group then they won't know what to do. The OP sounds like he doesn't know how to do that. Had you provided code then this would have been a complete answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @Enigmativity Did you give the OP the opportunity to express himself? No, because you are capable of OP mind reading. Your contribution is to discourage positive contribution. I personally believe that we should put people on the right track and follow up rather than spoon feeding. That's the way people learn. Anyway, this kind of contribution is what makes Stackoverflow toxic at times and makes this community appears in memes.